# Advantages/Disadvantages Using Theme Editor Instead of Pages

Tags: theme-development, pages

I'm working on a site and I prefer to create the site using the WordPress pages system. A co-collaborator assisting me with the site prefers to add pages using Theme Editor.

My first thought what is the advantage in doing this instead adding a new page via the dashboard?

Are there any disadvantages in creating pages using the theme editor?

If I wanted to use a plugin would the theme editor be able to use that plugin? Or does it isolate itself some how?

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by theme editor? I assume not this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_SubPanel Sounds like a plugin to me.

Comment: Correct that is the theme editor that I am speaking of. If you were to go to your dashboard you will see it listed there as well. Was just curious to know why a site creator would chose that over simply making pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that the theme editor is used to change the code structure of the pages something that cannot be achieved by simply creating a page via dashboard.

These are two very different things, while you can add html on your page using the page editor you cannot add some Php there. In simple terms theme editor allows you to edit the structure of pages, styling and create new page templates as well.

To use theme editor to make changes you need to have some Php knowledge or CSS for styling.

Comment: Could a site creator who uses theme editor could they interact with plugins they have installed on their WordPress site easily?

Comment: Plugins have their own editor like theme editor that is accessible under dashboard menu plugins>editor ...its very different from theme editor.